# Configuration of ILO port on HP servers

Tags: hp, hp-proliant, ilo

I have a HP server that has ILO port. How can i configure it to use from remote location? server os is debian-squeez.

Comment: Are you configuring ILO remotely, or configuring ILO locally and trying to get it to work remotely? Also, which HP server model?

Comment: I want to configure it remotely to work it remotely :)

Comment: Sounds like a catch-22 situation. You need to configure ILO to work remotely, but you need to get on ILO to do that, but you can't because ILO isn't configured to work remotely, *ad infinitum*. You might want to try calling up your provider.

Comment: i have remote access by ssh to server.

Answer (score 10):

You can configure the ILO from the running operating system using the HP Online Configuration (hponcfg) utility.

[Download the HP packages for *your* OS as detailed here.](http://blog.bat.ru/projects/admin/wiki/HP_ProLiant_management_tools_for_UbuntuDebian_based_server) You may as well use this as an opportunity to install all of the agents for your server.

However, the main package you need is the `hponcfg` utility.

```
apt-get install hponcfg
```

Here's a description of the command usage.

```
# hponcfg -h

Firmware Revision = 1.94 Device type = iLO Driver name = hpilo
HPONCFG RILOE II/iLO setup and configuration utility
Version 3.1.0 (c) Hewlett-Packard Company, 2010


-h,  --help           Display this message
-?                    Display this message
-r,  --reset          Reset the RILOE II/iLO to factory default
-f,  --file           Get/Set RILOE II/iLO configuration from "filename" 
-i,  --input          Get/Set RILOE II/iLO configuration from the XML input
                      received through the standard input stream.
-w,  --writeconfig    Write the RILOE II/iLO configuration to "filename" 
-a,  --all            Capture complete iLO configuration to the file.
                      This should be used along with '-w' option
-l,  --log            Log replies to "filename" 
-v,  --xmlverbose     Display all the responses from RILOE II/iLO
-s,  --substitute     Substitute variables present in input config file
                      with values specified in "namevaluepairs" 
-g,  --get_hostinfo   Get the Host information
-m,  --minfwlevel     Minimum firmware level
```

Using this tool, you will be able to supply an XML file as input containing some basic parameters for the ILO, like username, password, IP configuration, etc.

What may be easier in this case would be obtaining the ILO's current config using `hponcfg -w ILO.xml`, modifying the file to contain the IP and configuration you wish, then reconfiguring the ILO with the altered file with `hponcfg -f ILO.xml`.

---

Of course, if you have remote hands or someone with physical access to the server, [this manual process works as well.](http://808techblog.com/2009/08/configure-hp-integrated-lights.html)

Answer (score 3):

- Note the administrator password from the service tag.
- Press F8 on server boot

You then get the iLO setup screen where you can set the IP/NM/DG and add a new user/password (do this, don't change the administrator password, not just yet anyway).

They you can just cable up the port and browse to the web interface - it's as simple as that.

Comment: the OP states that this needs to be done remotely! Of course, he may be able to instruct someone to do this.

Comment: Sorry, read it as he wanted to configure it to BE USED remotely - not that he wanted to configure it from a remote location - I'm a brit, forgive me for reading things too literally, it's a failing.

Comment: @Dan, I also read it as he wants to use it remotely (why else would you want iLO), not that he needs to configure it remotely.

Comment: @Chopper3 Hey - don't use being a Brit as an excuse (Check my profile)

Comment: @Chopper3 - I must admit, now I've read it again, I can see what you mean! He did clarify in the comments, though.

Answer (score 1):

If you have installed using HP SmartStart then you may have the "HP Lights-Out Online Configuration Utility" installed to the following location:

[Program Files]\HP\hponcfg\hponcfg_gui.exe

If not, then you may be able to download it from here:

http://h20000.www2.hp.com/bizsupport/TechSupport/SoftwareIndex.jsp?lang=en&cc=us&prodNameId=1135772&prodTypeId=18964&prodSeriesId=1146658&swLang=8&taskId=135&swEnvOID=1005

Comment: Sorry but installed what? I just know the server has ILO port,i haven't done anything about ILO on the server,i just installed OS on it and configure some of its services.And also the OS is Debian not Windows

Comment: Ah, you didn't say that :) Sorry then, I don't do Linux. SmartStart is a HP Util for quickly installing Operating Systems with the correct HP drivers and tools etc - but I suspect it's Windows only.

Comment: I edited my question to mention the OS type. thank you anyway.

Comment: DON'T follow Dan's link, the domain is now owned by a squatter and shows no useful content.

Answer (score 0):

Found a link, thought of sharing.

[How to Configure iLO on your HP Proliant Server](http://www.tricksguide.com/how-to-configure-ilo-on-your-hp-proliant-server.html)

May be it helps all.

Comment: Really not helpful as this covers configuring iLO from the BIOS. The BIOS is not available on a remote server as stated in the Question.

Comment: Also the link is now dead, which is why only posting a link is discouraged. In future please add the revelant text to your answer, by all means link to the original page to give credit.

Answer (score 0):

If the server is running WIndows OS, then we can use HP Lights-Out Online Configuration Utility (HPONCFG.exe utility) for Windows. This is a simple GUI and we can easily reset the password. This utility does not ask for any password when you launch it. Moreover, when you reset the iLO password, HPONCFG will not ask for the previous password.

If we use this method, then we do not have to turn OFF the server and use the System Maintenance switch (iLO Security Override Switch) available on the Server system board.

For more information, may be the link provided below will be worth to look,

How to reset iLO Administrator password of HP Server

http://www.tricksguide.com/reset-ilo-forgot-administrator-password-of-hp-proliant-server.html

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

The manual process that ewwhite linked to in his post can be found (salvaged) here http://hp-ilo.blogspot.com/#!