# Access HP Lights-Out from remote server

Tags: ip, hp, hp-proliant

I have a HP Server on Co-location that i administrate using HP Light-Out and remote desktop to windows.

The problem is that the Lights-Out ip now is gone (not working any longer) but the remote desktop ip works just fine. How can i access the Lights-Out web site from the remote server without knowing what ip it got, or is there a way to find it in windows?

BR
Andreas

Comment: Do you know the particular server model and generation? E.g. ProLiant DL380 G5?

Answer (score 4):

You would need to have the HP Management Agents (for your particular Windows Server version) installed in order to be able to run the `hponcfg` utility. This tool allows you to reprogram, reconfigure or reset your system's ILO.

If you can handle a reboot and smart hands is available for the remote facility, [this manual process](http://808techblog.com/2009/08/configure-hp-integrated-lights.html) works as well.

Also see: [Configuration of ILO port on HP servers](https://serverfault.com/questions/334424/configuration-of-ilo-port-on-hp-servers)

Answer (score 2):

#### hponcfg

search google 'HP Lights-Out Online Configuration Utility for Windows' or 'HP Lights-Out Online Configuration Utility for Linux' to access the following site:

http://h20000.www2.hp.com/bizsupport/TechSupport/SoftwareIndex.jsp?lang=en&cc=us&prodNameId=1135772&prodTypeId=18964&prodSeriesId=1146658&swLang=8&taskId=135&swEnvOID=1005

C:\Program Files\HP\hponcfg>hponcfg /w iLo.xml

This will export the current settings from ILO, you can modify it then import it:

C:\Program Files\HP\hponcfg>hponcfg /f ilo.xml

Shamelessly stolen from:
http://linuxtechres.blogspot.com/2011/10/how-to-get-hp-ilo-ip-address.html