# Two HP iLOs have gone unresponsive, and are in a colo. Is there any way to remotely troubleshoot?

Tags: hp, networking, ilo

We have two DL360 G5s that suddenly lost iLO connectivity. They are at a remote site, so I cannot do any physical troubleshooting (yet). Is there any way I can remotely troubleshoot the iLO? Currently they cannot be accessed in a web browser, and cannot be pinged.

If I do eventually get physical access, what should I do (besides reconnecting/replacing the cable)?

OS: Linux

Comment: Do you have access to the operating systems running on the servers?

Comment: Yes we are running Linux on them

Comment: If you do not have connectivity to your host OS, have you check the switch ports?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you have access to the operating systems running on the servers (you did not indicate which), you can program the ILO using the `hponcfg` utility.

The things you can do here are listed in the command's help, with the "-r" flag actually resetting the ILO to default. I would try something less sever first, like "-w" which writes the ILO's configuration to a file. Maybe your device obtained a DHCP address or lost some settings.

```
hponcfg  -?
hponcfg  -h
hponcfg  -m minFw
hponcfg  -r [-m minFw ]
hponcfg  [-a] -w filename [-m minFw]
hponcfg  -g [-m minFw]
hponcfg  -f filename [-l filename] [-s namevaluepair] [-v] [-m minFw]
hponcfg  -i [-l filename] [-s namevaluepair] [-v] [-m minFw]

-h,  --help           Display this message
-?                    Display this message
-r,  --reset          Reset the RILOE II/iLO to factory default
-f,  --file           Get/Set RILOE II/iLO configuration from "filename" 
-i,  --input          Get/Set RILOE II/iLO configuration from the XML input 
                      received through the standard input stream.
-w,  --writeconfig    Write the RILOE II/iLO configuration to "filename"
-a,  --all            Capture complete iLO configuration to the file.
                      This should be used along with '-w' option
-l,  --log            Log replies to "filename"
-v,  --xmlverbose     Display all the responses from RILOE II/iLO
-s,  --substitute     Substitute variables present in input config file
                      with values specified in "namevaluepairs"
-g,  --get_hostinfo   Get the Host information
-m,  --minfwlevel     Minimum firmware level
```

See: [HP ILO 3 gives XML syntax errors with hponcfg utility](https://serverfault.com/questions/460578/hp-ilo-3-gives-xml-syntax-errors-with-hponcfg-utility) or [Access HP Lights-Out from remote server](https://serverfault.com/questions/353109/access-hp-lights-out-from-remote-server)

Comment: Okay, looks like we might have to regen the xml files. I'll take care of this Monday and let you know how it goes.

Comment: Thanks. This should solve your issue, though. You can also modify the XML output and import it back in to overwrite the ILO's config.