# Password setting for IPMI in Linux

Tags: hp, ilo, ipmitool

I am trying to configure IPMI in my HP ProLiant Servers. Configuration looks successful , but somewhat confused with the 'Administrator' user account .

Following are some information on IPMI in one of my server:

```
# ipmitool user list 2
ID  Name             Callin  Link Auth  IPMI Msg   Channel Priv Limit
1   Administrator    true    false      true       ADMINISTRATOR
2   admin             true    false      true       USER
3   (Empty User)     true    false      false      NO ACCESS
4   (Empty User)     true    false      false      NO ACCESS
______________________________

]# ipmitool channel getciphers ipmi 2 
ID   IANA    Auth Alg        Integrity Alg   Confidentiality Alg
0    N/A     none            none            none           
1    N/A     hmac_sha1       none            none           
2    N/A     hmac_sha1       hmac_sha1_96    none           
3    N/A     hmac_sha1       hmac_sha1_96    aes_cbc_128
```

The confusion is regarding the password for Administrator Account. Do I need to set the password for Administrator account or by default if any password is Set ? 
For HP Servers that supports ILO , i think it comes with A random, eight-character, alphanumeric string which is  printed on a little cardboard card attached to the server . Is this is the password for Administrator Account ? .

Also  One more clarification needed regarding the 'Administrator' account is it disabled by default for logging to the IPMI enabled device remotely. I am getting the following error. 
  =============================                                         
 #ipmitool -I lanplus -H 192.168.2.153 -U Administrator  sel elist 
Password: 

 Error: Unable to establish IPMI v2 / RMCP+ session  

 Get SEL Info command failed        

 ============================                                                   
 But if I try to connect using the 'admin' user that I created it works fine   
 ======================                                                      
   # ipmitool -I lanplus -H 192.168.2.153 -U admin  -L USER sel elist 

 Password: 

 SEL has no entries 

 ======================                                                           
 Please clarify .

Answer (score 4):

Yes, the password on the asset tag is the default password for the Administrator account. The user name is "Administrator" (case-sensitive).

I'm curious as to why you're using ipmitool when there are already HP tools for managing the ILO subsystem. Look into the `hponcfg` tool, which has a specific set of commands for managing the ILO from within the host operating system.

Also see: [Configuration of ILO port on HP servers](https://serverfault.com/questions/334424/configuration-of-ilo-port-on-hp-servers/334446#334446)

Comment: I was configuring HA Clustering. So, I am planning to use two fencing device for the setup . One is HP ILo and other IPMI fencing as secondary backup. So , thought that before configuring IPMI as fencing device , was trying to understand the working of ipmi .

Answer (score -1):

In my experience with HP servers, the default username for iLO access is Administrator and password and DNS name are located on the tag.  Sometimes it is changed during provisioning so Google "HP ilo password reset" for some options if the tag creds don't work.

Comment: Most people come here from Google. We really don't like sending them back there - that's not our mission.